# Linking error in Cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, nvcc

I have problem trying to build basic cuda/thrust code to get more familiar with GPU programming. I am probably not compiling it properly so I would like to know what I am doing wrong?

I am building using the following instructions

```
nvcc -c gpu_functions.cu
nvcc gpu_functions.o gpu_test.cu -o gpu_test
```

However I get a linking error:

```
jim@pezbox:~/dev/analytics/src$ nvcc gpu_functions.o gpu_test.cu -o gpu_test
/tmp/tmpxft_00002383_00000000-14_gpu_test.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_00002383_00000000-3_gpu_test.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `void add<thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int> > >(thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int> > const&, thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int> > const&, thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int> >&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have three files:

1. gpu_functions.h (the header function for the GPU functions)
2. gpu_functions.cu (the implementation for the GPU functions)
3. gpu_test.cu (the main loop that calls my defined GPU functions)

gpu_functions.h

```
template<typename Vector>
void add(const Vector& in1, const Vector& in2, Vector& out);
```

gpu_functions.cu

```
#include "gpu_functions.h"
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/replace.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

using namespace thrust;

template<typename Vector>
void add(const Vector& in1, const Vector& in2, Vector& out) {
transform(in1.begin(), in1.end(), in2.begin(), out.begin(), 
          plus<typename Vector::value_type>()); 
}
```

gpu_test.cu

```
#include "piston_functions.h"
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace thrust;

int main(void) {
    const int n = 100000000;
    // allocate three device_vectors with 10 elements
    device_vector<int> in1(n, 1);
    device_vector<int> in2(n, 2);
    device_vector<int> out(n, 0);

    add(in1, in2, out);

    thrust::copy(out.begin(), out.begin()+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;    
}
```

I am probably doing something stupid or I have missed something very obvious.

Comment: When using templates, all explicit specialization declarations must be visible at the time of the template instantiation. In your case, `add` is defined in `gpu_functions.cu` but not instantiated and there is nothing to be visible in `gpu_test.cu`. Try moving the definition of `add` from `gpu_functions.cu` to `gpu_test.cu`.

Comment: @JackOLantern please post this as an answer.

Comment: @harrism I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Once declared, templated functions need an explicit or implicit instantiation, namely, generating a concrete function (instance) for a particular combination of template arguments.

In the `gpu_functions.cu` compilation unit, you are missing both. In other words, the compiler is not generating an instance of the function `add` so that the linker doesn't find anything to link.

You should fix this problem by including the templated function declaration at the location where you are implicitly instantiating it, that is, the compilation unit comprising the `main` function.

In other words, the code below will compile correctly

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace thrust;

template<typename Vector>
void add(const Vector& in1, const Vector& in2, Vector& out) {
transform(in1.begin(), in1.end(), in2.begin(), out.begin(), 
    plus<typename Vector::value_type>()); 
}

int main(void) {
    const int n = 100000000;
    device_vector<int> in1(n, 1);
    device_vector<int> in2(n, 2);
    device_vector<int> out(n, 0);

    add(in1, in2, out);

    thrust::copy(out.begin(), out.begin()+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;    
}
```

Of course, you can move the templated function declaration in a separate `.cuh` file and including it by a `#include` directive.

Finally, always remember to add [CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).